# retain value after validation failed

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a php project online appointment form which using multiple select option list and hide select option.

I have problem on retain value from the select option after validation failed.

My select option are triggered one just like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3UWk2/3/),

the 1st select option value will triggered 2nd select option, then the 2nd select option value will triggered a image. The 1st select option value are retain but the 2nd select option value are reset.

I can retain value but when user want to change to other option, the value at old option still remain there and it will append with the new value. What I want is if user change other option it will automatically reset to null, but after validation failed it retain.

I'm using clear value with this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Service').change(function(){    
  $('#selectOp1').prop('selectedIndex',0);
  $('#selectOp2').prop('selectedIndex',0);
  $('#selectOp3').prop('selectedIndex',0);
  $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); //this one for hide the image
)};
```

but when validation failed, the selected value also gone, and this is very irritating.
Can someone help me what are the choice I have, I'm very new in jquery

Comment: i don't see any reset or image in your fiddle.

Comment: I think you have not put all your code in fiddle. I dont find the code  in fiddle which is posted here

Comment: he has just given it like a sample how his select works

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can try this this will reset your select box values also 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Rank').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected

            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want

            $('div.container div').children().each(function(){

                $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){

                   if(attrib.name != value)
                   {
                       $('#'+value).prop('selectedIndex',0);
                   }

                  });
             });

            var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements

         //master reset
        }else{

            $('#airman').prop('selectedIndex',0);

            $('#senior-airman').prop('selectedIndex',0);

            var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide();            
        }

    }).trigger('change');

    $('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want

        //reset the child and      
        }else{

            var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
<!-- Site JavaScript -->
<select size="1" id="Rank" title="" name="Rank">
    <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
    <option value="airman">Airman</option>
    <option value="senior-airman">Senior Airman</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
    <div class="airman">
        <select class="second-level-select" id='airman'>
            <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-1">Basic Ore Miner - Level 1</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-2">Basic Ore Miner - Level 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="senior-airman">
        <select class="second-level-select" id='senior-airman'>
            <option value="">-Select Your Rank-</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-1">Omber Miner - Level 1</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-2">Omber Miner - Level 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="second-level-container">    
    <div class="basic-ore-1">
        Line of text for basic ore miner 1
    </div>
    <div class="basic-ore-2">
        Line of text for basic ore miner 2
    </div>
    <div class="omber-miner-1">
        Line of text for omber miner 1
    </div>
    <div class="omber-miner-2">
        Line of text for omber miner 2
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: this jquery are only hide select option but it didn't clear or reset the value inside to null isn't it?

Comment: it's clears your message ""basic-ore-1" class tag and related messages  and reset the select box values also

Comment: what i want is clear the value of the select option because i need only one value to be inserted into database. How to make it? the message I can make hide if user choose other value

Comment: to make it clear what I want, when user select value at #selectOp1, the other value at #selectOp2 and #selectOp3 reset to null, same goes to when user select value at #selectOp2, the other two Op1 and Op3 reset to null, I can make it but when validation fail, the value at last select are gone and user has to select the value again

Comment: check now if you choose one select box another one is getting reset.

Comment: the image are reset but the value still there. Let see whether it insert into database or not

Comment: the hidden value also insert into database, it doesn't clear the value, it clear the image only

Comment: I Couldn't see any of the hidden values in your HTML. If you want to reset those perform inside if or else according to your need

Comment: I guess I just use json style